# Adjusting touchpad drag threshold?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, drag-and-drop

I find my self constantly dragging text, links, icons, and other things a few pixels by accident. Can I somehow increase the drag threshold? I thought at first it was because I use a trackpad, but I get the same unwanted behavior with a plain old mouse.

I am using mostly Unity and sometimes GNOME in Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad. From there you can set Drag and Drop Threshold. I've got mine set pretty high for that reason.

Comment: That was only too obvious once you know where to look. Thank you!